# What is the difference between a filebeat container input and a filebeat filestream input with a container parser?

Tags: filebeat

I notice that the filebeat [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-filestream.html#filestream-input-paths) suggests that the filestream input is the new and improved alternative to the log input.  I also notice that the documentation indicates that a container parser may be specified as a child of the filestream input configuration.  For example, filestream input:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  paths:
    - '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'
```

vs

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: filestream
  id: my-id
  paths:
    - '/var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log'
  parsers:
    - container:
```

Are these equivalent?  Why would I choose one over the other?

I am using filebeat 8.3 (current version as of this post) in a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

*Written when 8.12 was the current Elastic Stack version*

`log` input has been deprecated and will be removed, the fancy new `filestream` input [has replaced it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/8.12/migrate-to-filestream.html). That is the only simple part.

`container` wraps `log`, adding `format` and `stream` options.
From `container`'s [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/8.12/filebeat-input-container.html):
*This input searches for container logs under the given path, and parse them into common message lines, extracting timestamps too. Everything happens before line filtering, multiline, and JSON decoding, so this input can be used in combination with those settings.*

Since `log` is dead, the fate of container is actively being talked about [here](https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/34393), this includes implementing `filestream`'s `take_over` for `container` to safely migrate from it on existing deployments, or whatever ends up happening there as a migration path.

There is a [draft](https://github.com/elastic/beats/pull/36661) for `container_v2` that will wrap `filestream` instead and include the `stream` and `format` options, which is a bit odd, I do not understand why the processor would not fit the bill there already.

The specialties in the form of `stream` and `format` options are  already present in the `filestream`'s [parser option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/8.12/filebeat-input-filestream.html#_container), so I don't see why you'd use `container` if you are deploying it on a new machine.
Even the [autodiscovery was switched](https://github.com/elastic/beats/pull/36950) from `container` to `filestream`.

TL;DR and a handy [migration guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/migrate-to-filestream.html)

- Use `filestream` over `log`/`container` in new deployments
- For old `container` deployments, you probably want to migrate to `filestream`, but since `take_over` is not implemented for it, you want to wait for the resolution of [this](https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/34393) issue.
- For old `log` deployments, you absolutely do want to migrate to `filestream`, as it is deprecated, `take_over` is supported for it in `filestream` as per the linked migration guide.